# SHA256 Digest authentication using DatasourceRealm tomcat 8.5

Tags: cryptography, tomcat8.5

I am trying to configure digest authentication using SHA256 hashing of the password and not able to authenticate even with the correct username

I created the datasource and realm configuration with credentailhandler algortihm set to SHA-256 and used the username:realmname:password to create the sha256 digest on mysql. But it does not work.